# Does the MCP4725 support clock stretching? Does DMA need clock stretching in STM32F7?

Tags: stm32, i2c, dac, dma

I'm trying to send data to an [MCP4725](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22039d.pdf) through DMA in [STM32f746ng](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f746ng.pdf) but I can't.

I'm thinking maybe DMA requires clock stretching and the MCP4725 does not support it? (I couldn't find anything about clock stretching in MCP's datasheet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the MCP4725 has no indication that it requires clock stretching.

But even if the MCP4725 did require clock stretching, the STM32 I2C peripheral will support it. The fact that DMA is used has nothing to do with clock stretching.

The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: My question was: is MPC support clock stretching? Since sending address and then after time data, I thought maybe DMA of stm32 force to use clock stretching feature.

Comment: The question does not make sense. As I explained already, that is not the way how clock stretching works. You are misunderstanding how clock stretching works according to the roles of devices. If slave requires it, master must support it, and STM32 does support it, so it is irrelevant if slave requires it or not. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: STM32cubeIDE listed under it's slave feature named: Clock no stretch mode. It means slave have feature of not supporting stretch because this ability is bad ability?

Comment: The STM32 is not the slave so the setting does not matter. Please read the manuals and API documentation.

Comment: I know, I mean MCP as slave not STM, but referred to it's manual doc also it can act as slave, thank you so much.